# Best way to deal with index out of bound error

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have generated a time signal and calculated its zero up crossings. Now I would like to calculate the period of two successive zero up-crossings. The best option I though was to use for loops with indexing. However then I run into the "index out of bounds" error at my boundary.

Here is my code:

```
t = 0:0.1:20;       % time
A = 3;              % Amplitude
x = A*sin(t);       % Signal

find_zero = diff(sign(x));
indx_up = find(find_zero>0);       % find all upward going zero crossing index values

time = t(indx_up);                 % time values for zero crossings

for ii = 1:length(time)
    period(ii) = time(ii+1)-time(ii);
end
```

The error I receive: `Attempted to access time(5); index out of bounds because numel(time)=4`.

Is there a way around it?

Comment: you could use `for ii = 1:length(time)-1` if you want to use `time(ii+1)` in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want

```
for ii = 1:length(time)-1
```

but can't you just replace your whole loop with `period = diff(time)`?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, and @Dan you are right about that second option!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are accessing `time(ii+1)` when `ii` goes from 1 to `length(time)`.  The problem will be fixed if you change the for loop to

```
for ii = 1:length(time)-1
```